# Poner la hora a input text en view html con jquery (no Php)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mvc

Como puedo poner por default la fecha de hoy a un input text al momento de ejecutar mi vista en html con jquery javascript?
Lo unico que he conseguido es este codigo, que si funciona pero no lo imprime en el input pero si en el cuerpo de la vista:

```html
    <script>
    var f = new Date();
document.write(f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear());
    
</script>
```

esto muestra la fecha suelta en el cuerpo de la vista, ahora si quiero pintarlo en el input e intento esto, se vuelve una especie de bucle y na no me muestra mi formulario solo la fecha, como se muestra en la imagen:

```html
    <script>
    $("#FechaActual").ready(function){
    var f = new Date();
document.write(f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear());
    
    });    

</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay soluciones a este tema, por ejemplo me gusta esta función que ha creado @Owen [Aquí la solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16958005/9578298)

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y con qué problemas/dificultades te estás encontrando? ¿Recibes algún mensaje de error? Esta pregunta es muy amplia y pobre en detalles. Por favor lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para añadir la información que falta.

Comment: Al menos di que has intentado, pasa el código del input y la hora, ayúdanos también a nosotros para que no sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Tiene razón, ahora mismo edito mi consulta, gracias.

Comment: @JuanFernandoDjJf agradecería revises mi respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Te coloco el siguiente ejemplo, donde puedes notar que para modificar
>   el valor de un input y que muestre la fecha por ejemplo; lo tienes que
>   hacer a través del método value.

1. En la variable fecha, creo un nueva instancia de `new Date()`
2. ahora con la variable fecha acceso a `getFullYear()` para obtener el año
3. ahora con la variable fecha acceso a `getMonth()` para obtener el mes
4. ahora con la variable fecha acceso a `getDate()` para obtener el dia

> Para insertar el valor dinámico dentro del input, primero lo obtengo a
>   través de su id y lo asigno a la variable **letrero**; después hago
>   que esa variable letrero acceda al método value y declaro que eso es
>   igual a mi día, mes y año

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="fecha">
<script>
  const letrero = document.querySelector("#fecha")

  const fecha = new Date();            
  let anio = fecha.getFullYear()
  let mes = fecha.getMonth()+1
  let dia = fecha.getDate()


  if(dia < 10){
  dia='0'+dia
  }
  if(mes < 10){
  mes='0'+mes
  }
  letrero.value = `${dia} / ${mes} / ${anio}`
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> El uso de template strings es para poder imprimir valores dinámicos
>   con cadenas de texto sin usar el signo de mas; lo que requieres es el
>   uso de las comillas invertidas y los valores dinámicos o mejor
>   conocidos como variables van con $ y entre llaves sencillas
>
> Como notas le sumo uno a el mes, esto ocurre por que JS lee los meses
>   como un arreglo y empieza desde la posición cero, entonces hay que
>   sumarle uno para igualar al mes en el que estas ejecutando el código

Agregué solo dos condicionales (if), para que cual el día y mes es menor a 10 le agregue un cero al inicio y en vez de leer **4/4/2018**, se lea **04/04/2018**

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tienes una estructura html ja implementada, en donde tienes un tag para el input text con un ID especifico. 
En este ejemplo estoy asumiendo que el ID que se asigna al input text es input_fecha.

El codigó en Jquery que propongo

```js
const ID = "#input_fecha" //cambiarlo por el ID de tu input tag
$(document).ready(function(){

   //Declaración de variables
   var fechaActual;
   var input_fecha;
  
  //init fechaActual a null
  fechaActual = null;
  //Obteniendo el input del dom
  input_fecha = $(ID);
  fechaActual = obtenerFechaActual();
  input_fecha.val(fechaActual); //asignando fecha actual al input text
});


//Devuelve todo los datos relacionada con la fecha
//ejemplo Sun Apr 01 2018 20:49:05 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)
function obtenerFechaActual(){
 return new Date();
}
```

Comment: Hola MonsterKrod, te damos la bienvenida a la comunidad. Por favor lee [answer], donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus respuestas. En la medida de lo posible, no se debería responder a preguntas incompletas o a la que le faltan detalles importantes. Un saludo.

Comment: @MonsterKrod te felicito por tu interés en ayudar!! sin embargo no entiendo tu respuesta, seria conveniente explicaras brevemente lo que intentas hacer en tu ejemplo.